# decode json from gnip with php

Tags: php, json

I have been at this for hours and cant for the life of me figure out how to decode this json file. I am using gnip to capture twitter data. Gnip is returning the data in JSON format. I need a way to decode this in php and be able to access each of the json objects. I have worked with json before but I am not able to wrap my mind around this one. One funny thing i came across during simple testing was if i have a json code like this

```
{"foo":123}
```

I can decode this using the json_decode() function. But if the json is formatted like this

```
{

 "foo":123


}
```

it doesnt decode :/

Here is a link to the json code:

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/myjson.json?w=b7ad8e2c

if this link doesnt work this should

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/57604377/myjson.json

I tried to access it like this.

i put all of this json code inside a file and read the file and put the contents into a variable called $json
then,

```
$obj = json_decode($json)
```

i tried both these methods to access the value of "id" for starters

```
echo $obj->id
```

and

```
echo $obj->{'id'}
```

it doesnt return anything

I hope some of you brilliant people can give me some insights into this.

Comment: Your formatted JSON is valid, and is parsed by `json_decode` correctly: http://codepad.org/HJmVMaEr

Comment: Using the data from the second link json_decode works for me, too. php 5.4.7/win32

Comment: What is var dump of $json and $obj

Answer (score 1):

Given this code in a file called json.php:

```
<?
  $json = file_get_contents("php://stdin");

  $obj = json_decode($json);
  var_dump($obj);

  // Different echos go here
?>
```

And cat'ing in your test file

```
cat multiline_gnip.json | php json.php
```

Then the following work for me:

```
echo $obj->id
echo $obj->{id}
echo $obj->{'id'}
```

Changing the json_decode line to:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

Gives me back an associative array and then this works:

```
echo $obj["id"]
```

Mind sharing some of the code you're using for parsing this?

And for completeness here is my php --version

PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

(Disclaimer: I work for Gnip)

Answer (score 0):

You should use php cli to test your functions & data.
It should be fairly straightforward to spot your bug from there.